# Should I add landscape rock before or after installing a fence around a dog pen?

Tags: fence, landscaping

I am making a 20'x15' dog pen area. The L-shaped fence will be against the house on each end. This is new construction, so I'm waiting on final grade.

Should I install the fence, leaving a 5" gap between the bottom rail and ground, then after the fence is done, bring in 3" of 1.5" rock? The fence manufacturer recommends 2" clearance between ground and bottom rail.

Or, should I bring in 3" of rock first, then install the fence?

Comment: FYI: Dogs will dig in stones if they are determined enough to get out, bored, or just feel like digging.

Comment: we have 2 lhasa apso's who would role over and die if they had dirt on their paws!

Comment: Maybe *your* dogs won't dig, but other folks who stumble upon this question might own diggers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to put the rock down afterwards (or at least after setting the posts but before adding the fencing) as you won't have to deal with the rock being present while you are trying to dig holes for the posts.

Comment: What about installing the posts, pouring stone, then installing fence panels? Might make it easier to dump and spread stone without a fence in the way.